# I see rust on my outdoors incoming gas pipes on the utility side of the meter - is it bad enough to call the gas company?

Tags: pipe, gas, corrosion

Our gas was installed between 50 and 70 years ago. The outdoors piping on the house side of the meter looks fine, with just a few traces of rust. However, the pipe on the utility side of the meter has areas of more extensive rust - are they serious enough for me to ask the utility to come out and look at it?

Utility side pipe and homeowner side pipe sections:
[image: Utility side pipe and homeowner side pipe sections]

Shut off valve area
[image: Shut off valve area]

Pipe rising from underground run from street
[image: Pipe rising from underground run from street]

Comment: Probably can get away with a bit of sanding and paint for the above ground rust.  I would be quite worried about the underground pipe after 50/70 years.  The utility probably needs to approve any work, at least on their side.

Comment: @crip659 I'm not planning on touching the utility side piping. Sounds like I won't be crying wolf if I give them a call at least.

Comment: The above ground just seems like heavy surface rust, has not started eating into the metal.  It is more of let them know and they can come by and fix it in a year or two.  Even the pipe coming out of the ground does not look too bad.

Comment: it looks like someone has made a half-arsed attempt to spray paint it.

Comment: AFAIK, nobody has touched it in 40-50 years.

Comment: If it rusts through it won't catastrophically rip open and explode...it'll develop a pinhole leak somewhere that your nose will be able to detect very quickly.

Comment: @knowitall   False smelling gas reporting usually not a good idea, it is usually an emergency response(at least I hope so).  Right now OPs problem seems to be cosmetic only for now.

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned you can email them these photos. They'll know what to do.